# new String(byte[]) gives different results when I put it in vs pull it out of the database

Tags: java, postgresql, character-encoding, file-encodings, glassfish-2.x

Before I save a byte array to the database if I print the output of `new String(data)` it returns a readable string like "foobar" but after I pull it out of the database, `new String(data)` will read like a bunch of gibberish like "9238929384739427349327...".  There's so many parts here I'll just try to list them all.  I'm using eclipselink and my data column is defined:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "data")
private byte[] data;
```

If I run this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
}
```

It outputs `windows-1250`.

My database is defined as:

```
CREATE DATABASE project_trunk
  WITH OWNER = project
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

I've also tried this on a DB defined like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE project_trunk
  WITH OWNER = project
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

And the problem still occurs.

I think what's happening is my database has a different encoding from my appserver.  When I put things into the database and pull it out again, it decodes it the wrong way so it looks like gibberish.  Am I on to something there?

Now when it comes to a solution to this problem, I'm a little confused.  I think what I should be doing is changing my appserver's file encoding to be the same as the database.  I'm using Glassfish 2.1.1.  When I go to `application server -> advanced -> domain attributes` and set the Locale to "UTF8" or "UTF-8" it tells me a restart is required.  After I restart glassfish, that field is still blank and I still get the error.  I think maybe it isn't saving the property.  I'd manually put it in the configuration file, but I don't know where or what to put.

Alternatively, I tried creating my database with an ENCODING = 'WIN1250' but when I do that it says my LC_CTYPE needs to be "WIN1252".  When I set LC_CTYPE to "WIN1252" it says that encoding doesn't exist.

---

I'm spending a lot of time on this, I'd like to know if I'm on to something here.  Does my theory of "out of sync encodings between appserver and db" sound correct, or am I chasing a red herring?  If anyone could help me figure out how to change this setting for glassfish 2.1.1 that'd also be very helpful.  Thanks

EDIT: People are asking why I'm storing Strings as raw bytes.  That's not exactly what I'm doing, sometimes the raw bytes represent an image or a pdf or a binary, sometimes it's text.  My **test** is inserting a plain text String and pulling it back out to make sure it got saved correctly.  This test passes on our CI server which is on linux.

EDIT2: I was asked to show the raw binary input vs raw binary output.

> Expected :[116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 109, 121, 32, 97, 116, 116, 97, 99, 104, 109, 101, 110, 116, 32, 97, 115, 32, 97, 32, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]
>
> Actual   :[60, 54, 56, 54, 57, 55, 51, 50, 48, 54, 57, 55, 51, 50, 48, 54, 100, 55, 57, 50, 48, 54, 49, 55, 52, 55, 52, 54, 49, 54, 51, 54, 56, 54, 100, 54, 53, 54, 101, 55, 52, 50, 48, 54, 49, 55, 51, 50, 48, 54, 49, 50, 48, 53, 51, 55, 52, 55, 50, 54, 57, 54, 101, 54, 55]

I gave this same test that checks the bytes to my coworker who's on a mac, and it passes for him.

Comment: Use the [`String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], java.nio.charset.Charset)) constuctor.

Comment: Does your byte array actually represent text? If so, why do you have it in a `byte[]`? If not, you shouldn't be using a `String`...

Comment: Also ... why are you storing `Strings` as raw bytes?

Comment: @jlordo I did this in my code `new String(attachment.getData(), Charset.lookup("UTF8"))` and it still printed out "87474703a2f2f6269742e6c792f617948363977".

Comment: I've edited the bottom to explain why I'm saving a String as a byte array.

Comment: Assuming the gibberish you're getting is actual output you're seeing, it strikes me as odd that it would be all hexadecimal digits instead of utter binary garbage. If that's true I'm not sure this is a charset error.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but the input string is `http://bit.ly/ayH69w`

Comment: @tieTYT: The HTML, or the images?

Comment: @tieTYT: I can't find `Charset.lookup(String)` in JavaDoc... where does this method come from?

Comment: @JonSkeet That's the actual String I'm using as input

Comment: You mean the URL? It would have been helpful to put it in quotes. Anyway, I've answered the question now.

Comment: @jlordo My mistake. The debugger gave me that option as a method to use.  I changed it to `forName` and got the same gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sometimes the raw bytes represent an image or a pdf or a binary, sometimes it's text

Okay, then you shouldn't be storing them as text.

Regardless of what's currently going wrong, even if you can get this to work for data which is *actually* text, you've got problems coming later on.

If you *must* store arbitrary binary data as text, you should use base64 to encode it - that way you can get back to the original binary with no problems. (You've only got to be able to transport ASCII strings around, and that's usually reasonably easy.) There are lots of third-party libraries for Base64; I like [this self-contained public domain one](http://iharder.net/base64).

Alternatively, store the data *as* binary data in the database, e.g. using a field of the [`bytea`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-binary.html) data type. That way you shouldn't need to do any conversion work: you should just be able to put it into the database as a byte array, and get it out as a byte array.

EDIT: Okay, it looks like you're getting back the *hex* representation of the binary data, but in ASCII. That's distinctly odd.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not communicating very well.  I'm not storing the binary as text, I'm storing the binary as binary.  But to test that the binary I put in is the same as the binary I pull out, I'm using `new String(...)` on the binary data.  When that string happens to be text, it's obvious that it came out differently.  In the DB, it is a bytea, and in JPA it's an @Lob

Comment: @tieTYT: Don't convert it to a string at all. That's just clouding the issue (very significantly). Why don't you post the *exact bytes* before and after? `Arrays.toString(byte[])` should be fine to get diagnostic data. When you're *only* dealing with binary data, everything you've posted about locales and character sets should be *completely* irrelevant.

Comment: OK, I edited my question with that information.  They look kind of far off.

Comment: In addition to that, I just gave this same test to my coworker who's using a Mac and the test passes

Comment: @tieTYT: It looks like you're getting hex back (each byte of input is returned as two bytes of output, which decoded as ASCII would be the hex representation). Can you reproduce this with a short but complete program? Is your coworker with a Mac using the same code and the same versions of all libraries?

Comment: re: my coworker, I think it's pretty safe to say yes.  We may be a few days out of sync w/ regards to source code, but I've been having this issue for months and we all use maven so we should be getting the same libs.  My short but complete program would need to access the db to work because that's how I reproduce this. Would that be ok?

Comment: @tieTYT: Yes, that's fine. It would be nice to try to reproduce it, basically. Have you worked out whether the problem is how your code writes, or how your code reads? What happens if your colleague *reads* the data you've written?

Comment: I made a test case that passes for me.  http://pastebin.com/Ar6MfgUb This is connecting to the same database with a test table.  I think this suggests there's some code in the middle of our app that's modifying the input.

Comment: @tieTYT: Right. That wouldn't surprise me at all. Unfortunately that means it's going to be hard for us to help you further :(

Comment: Jon: That's ok, writing that stand alone test case was a worthwhile exercise I should have done earlier.  I found a different coworker, also on a mac, where this test fails for them.

Comment: Check out my answer, this is the real cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is caused by a way that PostgreSQL works in version 9 vs version 8.  Most of my coworkers were using version 8 but I recently got a new computer so I used the latest PostgreSQL.

You need to set the output_bytea to "escape".

[Getting nearly double the length when reading byte[] from postgres with jpa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181524/getting-nearly-double-the-length-when-reading-byte-from-postgres-with-jpa)

I didn't find the answer there sufficient though, but I found this on a mailing list and it fixed my issue:  http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTikkE-jQ9srZ9VL1JuJ5h=UCutx8ZLim+OfQ1T4z@mail.gmail.com

> Dear List ,
>
> recent change of bytea_output format from escape to hex in 9.0 apparently breaks
>   popular persistent session handling perl modules like Apache::Session::Postgres
>   which stores pickled data structures in bytea columns of db table.
>   It is difficult to guess the root cause from the exception thrown by
>   the said module.
>   The problem is fixed by adding
>   bytea_output='escape'  in postgresql.conf
>   and issuing a pg_ctl reload.
>
> Eg in RT application the error is:
>   error:  RT couldn't store your session.
>   This may mean that that the directory /blah/blah/foo/bar isn't
>   writable or a database table is missing or corrupt
>
> Regds
>   Rajesh Kumar Mallah.